# Continuity of a differential of a Banach-valued holomorphic map

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ let $F$ be a Banach space (in my case even a dual Banach space), and let $\varphi:U\to F$ be a holomorphic map. I seem to be able to prove that the differential map $D\varphi:U\times\mathbb{C}^{n}\to F$ defined by $$D\varphi (z,v)= \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(z+tv)-\varphi(z)}{t}$$ is holomorphic.

> Is there a reference for this assertion?

I tried to look into some sources on infinite-dimensional holomorphicity and could not find such a statement, but some of those sources are rather complicated, and so it is likely I missed it.

Comment: I'll take a look around, you are right that the situation is much more treacherous.

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [Continuity of a differential of a Banach-valued holomorphic map](https://mathoverflow.net/q/334978).